# Save Image on Long Click no download the image

Tags: android, image, savefiledialog

I have a fragment and inside it I added webview, I have an image in the `WebView` (in my website) but when I try to save it to my phone it give me nothing, no action even.

here's my fragment

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        final WebView.HitTestResult result = mWebView.getHitTestResult();
        if (result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE ||
                result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {

            //menu.setHeaderTitle(result.getExtra());
            menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Save Image")
                    .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

                            String DownloadImageURL = result.getExtra();

                            if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(DownloadImageURL)){

                                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(DownloadImageURL));
                                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                                downloadManager.enqueue(request);

                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Image save successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error to save image.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

what I got is, when I longclick on the image, it gave me 3 option, SAVE IMAGE, OPEN IMAGE, SHARE IMAGE. But when I try to select one of them, for example try to SAVE IMAGE, it just gives me nothing.

how to add an action like SAVE IMAGE to save the image to my mobile phone?

did I miss something in the code?
please help me

Comment: You dumped a ridiculous amount of code. Please remove nearly all. Only post code that does not work. And post only one problem.

Comment: ok update my question, how to fix this? to save image in gallery

Comment: So you are not seeing one of those Toast()s?